# Hybrid Left/Right Join based on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to retrieve a list of users from a database, along side their company name (if they have a company associated with them).  However, there are a couple gotchas:

1. Not all users have companies, but I still need to show these people in the list.
2. Even if a user has a company, that company could be soft-deleted (the record is still in the database, but is flagged with is_deleted = 1), and I don't want to show users that are associated with "deleted" companies.

So essentially I want to SELECT from the User table and LEFT JOIN the company table, but I don't want to include the User record at all if the company they are assigned to is_deleted.

My first inclination is that I would have to use a UNION to merge two queries together, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do it?

Using Mysql 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT U.name Username, C.name Company
FROM User U
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company C
ON U.companyid = C.id
WHERE C.id IS NULL OR C.is_deleted = 0
```

C.id IS NULL gets the users with no company, and C.is_deleted = 0 gets the users with companies that haven't been soft-deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try joining to a table that excludes the deleted companies:

```
SELECT U.Name, C.Name 
FROM User U LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName 
     FROM Company 
     WHERE is_deleted = 0) 
C ON U.CompanyId = C.CompanyId
```

Comment: But I would also like to include Users who do not have a company assigned to them at all.  It seems like this way only shows users that have a company, which could be done with a traditional INNER JOIN.

Comment: Then you can change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN. I have updated my answer.